# Random list combination and order

Tags: jquery

I want a list of different images with different texts. On load I want both the order of the images, and the order of text to randomize, but have each list item consist of one image and one text. And then I want to use this random combination for an url.

So let’s say I have:

```
<ul>
<li><img id="pic1" src="pic1.jpg" /> <h2>Cat</h2></li>
<li><img id="pic2" src="pic2.jpg" /> <h2>Dog</h2></li>
<li><img id="pic3" src="pic3.jpg" /> <h2>Elephant</h2></li>
</ul>
```

But I want this combination to be random, so the next visitor might see:

```
<ul>
<li><img id="pic2” src="pic2.jpg" /> <h2>Elephant</h2></li>
<li><img id="pic1” src="pic1.jpg" /> <h2>Dog</h2></li>
<li><img id="pic3” src="pic3.jpg" /> <h2>Cat</h2></li>
</ul>
```

Furthermore, I would also like to know the combination of text and image, and use this for an url, like so:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="/pic2_elephant"><img id="pic2" src="pic2.jpg" /> <h2>Elephant</h2></a></li>
<li><a href="/pic1_dog"><<img id="pic1" src="pic1.jpg" /> <h2>Dog</h2></li>
<li><a href="/pic3_cat"><<img id="pic3" src="pic3.jpg" /> <h2>Cat</h2></li>
</ul>
```

Hope someone can help me!

Comment: so two arrays, sort randomly, create elements

Comment: @epascarello - thank you for your answer. I am not very good at jquery, so could you be so kind to explain a bit further? I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I'll post my answer, but if @epascarello provides one after, I'll gladly take it down since he did provide the basics of what I'm showing, and I was working to provide the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brettgaynor/4d7nupe6/54/)

First of all I'd probably not use HTML defined content as the source of your lists (text and images). I'd used some sort of arrays to store those.

```
  var textList = ['Elephant', 'Dog', 'Cat'];
  var imgList = ['pic1.jpg', 'pic2.jpg', 'pic3.jpg']
```

Assuming that your arrays will always contain the same amount of data (ie will always be the same length), you can just loop the length of one and pick random from each array and generate you HTML from there:

```
var textList = ['Elephant', 'Dog', 'Cat'];
var imgList = ['pic1.jpg', 'pic2.jpg', 'pic3.jpg'];

var randomImgIndexArr = generateUniqueIndexArray([], imgList);
var randomTextIndexArr = generateUniqueIndexArray([], textList);

function generateUniqueIndexArray(array, list) {
  while(array.length < list.length) {
      var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length);
      if(array.indexOf(randomIndex) === -1) array.push(randomIndex);
  }

  return array;
}


textList.forEach(function(item, index) {
  var textStr = textList[randomTextIndexArr[index]];
  var image = imgList[randomImgIndexArr[index]];

  var li = $('<li/>');
  var aHref = $('<a/>', { href: textStr + '_' + image, text: textStr });
  var imgElm = $('<img/>', { src: image, id: image });

  $(li).append(aHref).append(imgElm).appendTo($('ul'));
});
```

Comment: thank you so much! Only problem now is it allows for repeats. For example a list can now use Cat multiple times. Do you know how to limit each item (image or text) to only be used once?

Comment: Good point. I updated my answer and fiddle to incorporate that. Basically, first generate an array of random numbers that correlate with the length of the arrays, then loop that and pick the items from each array at the random index.

Comment: again thank you very, very much! With this setup Dog is always together with pic2.jpg, is there a way to randomize this so both the order of the images and the combinations (image and text) are randomized?

Comment: PS: How do I make the image link to the url? (Thank you again, your help is extremely appreciated!)

Comment: @Cody Basically you'd need to have two random arrays of indexs like I've show aboove. Then when you loop one of your lists, just reference the index in those random arrays. I've updated my fiddle to show you that.

Comment: For you second question, what do you mean? The `src` for the `img` tag should work, but you'll have to have the images in the right place for the path to work.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.sort` along with a pseudo random callback function make a good bet. The built-in `Set` type can help in making sure both images src and captions to be unique.

The *textList* contains 1 more item than *imgList*. When one of the input array has more elements than the other one, the logic will drop items in excess from the longuest array so that items from both arrays can be associated using their index at the end of the process.

```js
let $list = $('ul')
  // Pseudo randomly return negative or positive number
  , sorter = () => 0.5-Math.random()
  // Use Set container for uniqueness
  , s = new Set()
  , setFilter = el => !s.has(el) && s.add(el)
  // Initialize, apply unique filter and shuffle both input lists
  , textList = ['Elephant', 'Elephant', 'Dog', 'Cat', 'Bird', 'Duck'].filter(setFilter).sort(sorter)
  , imgList = ['/img/pic1.jpg', '/img/pic1.jpg', '/img/pic2.jpg', '/img/pic3.jpg', '/img/pic4.jpg'].filter(setFilter).sort(sorter)
  // Prepare length adjustement
  , compared = textList.length >= imgList.length ? [textList, imgList]: [imgList, textList];
;

// Make sure both arrays have the same length.
compared[0].splice(compared[1].length);


// Associate every item from both (now randomized) lists
[...imgList].forEach(
    (img, i) => void $(`<li><a href="${img}"><h2>${textList[i]}</h2> (${img})</a>`).appendTo($list)
);
```

```css
body {font-size: 12px}
h2 {display: inline-block}
ul {list-style: none}
li {padding: 0; margin: 0} li ~ li {margin-top: 5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul></ul>
```